# Why am I getting the wrong result when getting the length of an array in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

Had a weird bug in my program, here's what I used to output:

```
print(packet.visitedNodes, packet.visitedNodes.length)
```

Here is the class:

```
class Packet {
  constructor(visitedNodes, data) {
    this.visitedNodes = visitedNodes;
    this.data = data;
  }
  
  toString() {
    return "{" + JSON.stringify(this.visitedNodes) + ", " + JSON.stringify(this.data) + "}";
  }
}
```

Here is a sample of the logs:

```
(2) [2, 0]    1
(2) [2, 1]    1
(2) [1, 2]    1
(3) [2, 1, 0] 2
(3) [2, 0, 1] 2
(3) [2, 1, 0] 3
(3) [0, 2, 1] 2
(3) [0, 2, 1] 2
(3) [2, 0, 1] 3
```

On the left you can see what the length should actually be (automatically output), followed by the array, and then the array.length. As you can see, there is a mismatch in lengths and I feel like I'm going crazy.

I wanted to post this and see if anyone has seen this issue, I couldn't find much on it. Could be something more but let's start here and I can provide more code if this issue is deeper.

Here is a basic example of the what I think the issue is based off of:

```
let a = [1, 2];

function setup() {
  print(a, a.length);
  a.push(3);
  print(a, a.length);
}
```

Output:

```
(3) [1, 2, 3] 2
(3) [1, 2, 3] 3
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. There's not enough code here to determine a problem. Thanks.

Comment: The console has live references to objects and arrays. So if `packet.visitedNodes` is modified, the console will show the updated value. Use `print(JSON.stringify(packet.visitedNodes), packet.visitedNodes.length);`

Comment: What is this called? Could you send me a link to somewhere I can read about this?

Comment: Also, this only affects printing to the console right? Shouldn't affect logic in my program?